# Java - Applet calling/invoking another Applet

Tags: java, japplet

I wrote earlier about the following problem and received an answer to use either Splash Screen or JDialog. As I was researching about the above 2 solutions, now I think that I might be able to solve my problem by using another applet.

The problem: Before my main applet GUI runs I need to download certain files to local PC for the GUI to work. Therefore, I am now thinking of having 2 applets where Applet1 downloads the files, Applet2 is the main GUI.

I would use the Splash Screen or JDialog but at the moment they don't seem to be what I need. How can I invoke Applet2 from Applet1 automatically in the same window, and fully close Applet1 once Applet1 is done downloading files? Is the Applet idea better solution for my problem than Splash Screen or JDialog?

Here is the code of my main applet (in this case it would be Applet2):

```
@Override
public void init() {

    /* Create and display the Applet2 once Applet1 is done */
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initComponents();//Draw the GUI 
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

My earilier post:
[Java - Pause initComponents from running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343949/java-pause-initcomponents-from-running)